# Replace text in cheditor

Tags: jquery

I have a CKEditor with the following:

```
<textarea id="messageText" name="messageText" rows="10">
<div id="footer">
<br />
<br />
Regads<br />
-----------<br />
admin
</div>
</textarea>
```

and I have to replace content within footer div with jquery

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#footer").html(newcontentgoeshere);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: @user1819936 what did it do?

Comment: It works only first time, but i use this jquery frequently with no page refresh